# Is "'as' + article + adjective + noun + 'as'" grammatically correct?

Tags: adverbs, comparisons, noun-phrases

> 1. The sentiments expressed in the tweets can be ***as accurate a measure as*** is found with traditional telephone surveys.

The sentence above is grammatically correct. 
I wonder if it is still ok when I write like this,

2. The sentiments expressed in the tweets can be ***as an accurate measure as*** is found with traditional telephone surveys.

Why is it grammatical or ungrammatical?

Plus, even if the second sentence is ungrammatical, can it be accepted in ordinary conversation? Thank you!

Comment: Stellar question. I hope you get a good answer!

Comment: Basic question. The original is grammatical. The rephrasing is ungrammatical. And "why" is not a question that makes sense in that context. That's like asking "why is weather". There is no why. It just so happens.

Comment: Also, what on Earth does "ungrammatically correct" even *mean?*

Comment: @RegDwigнt It's a good syntax question and deserves a good answer. Let someone have the opportunity of giving one.

Comment: @RegDwigнt This is a sophisticated but common construction. It follows very consistent grammatical rules. That second *as* there is a preposition, but the first is a degree adverb. This pattern is seen with other degree adverbs, consider *this big a problem*, *so drastic a measure* and so forth. So the *"why"* here is indeed a very good question that makes a lot of sense. This is not an idiom.

Answer (score 1):

Your rephrase isn't quite natural with "can be."  But let's suppose you'd said "The sentiments in the tweets can be treated as an accurate measure, as is found with traditional telephone surveys."  That's fine, but you've said that tweets are an accurate gauge, and that there are similar gauges to be found in analyzing traditional telephone surveys.  Your first version compares the two directly and found them to be equally accurate, which is a bit different.

Just about anything can be accepted in ordinary conversation because the person you're talking to can always ask "Huh?"